# You can not supply no "ons-page" element to "ons-navigator"

Tags: onsen-ui

On Android device I get this error while loading a onsenui page.
this is related to http://onsenui.io javascript library.

> You can not supply no "ons-page" element to "ons-navigator".

Comment: Can you show your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there was no ons-page, ons-navigator has nothing to navigate to :)

if you're not using inlined ons-page then make sure it loads a page:

```
<body ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <ons-navigator var="myNavigator" page="mainPage.html">
    </ons-navigator>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

As Vu Nguyen's answer is somewhat correct but it doesn't really explain the other scenarios where this might happen, I'll share my solution on this. For me the problem occurred when I upgraded to Onsen UI 1.3.0 from 1.1.4 and the point where I got this error was on `navigator.pushPage('page1.html')` where *page1.html* looked like this:

```
<ons-template id="page1.html">
  <ons-sliding-menu
        menu-page="menu.html"
        main-page="browse.html"
        side="left">
  </ons-sliding-menu>
</ons-template>
```

Now the Onsen UI fails to find *ons-page* which it didn't previously need for some reason. So the solution is to wrap the *ons-sliding-menu* within *ons-page* like this

```
<ons-template id="page1.html">
  <ons-page>
    <ons-sliding-menu
        menu-page="menu.html"
        main-page="browse.html"
        side="left">
    </ons-sliding-menu>
  </ons-page>
</ons-template>
```

Comment: I don't know why you got a downvote, but your answer solved my problem and you got my upvote and thanks!